# mysql, if row exists incrament value else insert row without key

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do something that may be too complicated for MySQL

If a row exists i'd like it to update a counter and if not insert the row...I did a search and found this...

```
$query = "insert into TABLE 
(`id`, `item`, `count`, `option1`, `option2`) 
values 
('$cartName', '$sku', 1, '$option1', '$option2')
on duplicate key 
update count = count + 1";
```

but I don't have a key in the table so the "on duplicate key" won't work, the query needs multiple ANDs to check the row based on the id, item, and 2 option values.

an added thing is to have mySQL return a count of all count values based on the item

This is what I have currently (modified from search :), does anyone know how to reduce this into a single query?

option1 and option2 are variable and could be null so that's why the 2 if statements and is called from AJAX so the $message is used to update the javascript client side.

```
$query = "update TABLENAME set count=count+1 where item='$item'";
if($option1) $query .= " AND option1='$option1'";
if($option2) $query .= " AND option2='$option2'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error:".mysql_error() );       

if (mysql_affected_rows()==0) {
    $query = "insert into $table11 (`id`, `item`, `count`, `option1`, `option2`) values ('$id', '$item', 1, '$option1', '$option2');";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error:".mysql_error() );
    }

//total count for all items with specific id
$query = "SELECT SUM(count) FROM TABLENAME WHERE id='$cartName'";
$result = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($query)) or die("Error:".mysql_error() );
$message = $result[0];
```

Comment: Doing conditional stuff in MySQL is tricky. I'd highly suggest doing the checks with PHP. 1. select the row with the ID that you're planning to insert. 2. If num_rows equals 0, then do an insert. If not, update the row.

Comment: Have your tried REPLACE INTO instead of INSERT INTO

Comment: So  put an identity column on it, Solve your problem and satisfy 1NF.

Comment: I tried a REPLACE INTO but attempts to increment in the query statement failed (count=count+1 and count++) unless i'm wording it wrong.

Comment: @tony you mean with a primary key? there can be more than 1 row with the same item so it fails to add another row if the options change and all 4 need to be checked to make sure it's the correct row...so i'm not sure how to set it up so the on duplicate checks all 4

Comment: a unique compound key on all four fields may be